# For loop that subsets data and writes those data to separate Excel templates

Tags: r, excel, loops, subset, xlconnect

Essentially I have a dataset that contains 1000s of rows of data for about 100 different facilities, differentiated by their "Facility IDs". For each of these facilities I'm trying to automate populating a separate Excel workbook FROM that overall data (so create a separate workbook for each facility's data). I'm able to get the code inside the loop to run no problem (the part where I make the Excel workbook from the data). I just can't seem to see what I'm doing wrong in the loop itself. Any feedback would be welcome! I've created a really simplified snippet of data and code for the sake of convenience.

See photo for table of example data `Transfers_ALL`:

[image]

```
> for (i in 1:length(uniq)){
  Transfers <- subset(data, Transfers_ALL$Facility_ID == uniq[i])

  #making empty matrix
  m <- (data.frame(matrix('', nrow = 60,ncol = 60), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)) 

  # places values in specific cells in the new empty matrix. 
  m[1:(1+length(Transfers$Facility_ID)-1),3]<- Transfers$Facility_ID
  m[1:(1+length(Transfers$Col1)-1),8] <- Transfers$Col1 # row#, column#

  ##' Puts the data from the new filled matrix into a pre-formatted excel workbook template. 
  wb <- XLConnect::loadWorkbook("test.xlsx", create=TRUE)
  setStyleAction(wb,XLC$"STYLE_ACTION.NONE")
  XLConnect::writeWorksheet(wb,m,"Sheet1",startRow=13,startCol=1,header=F)

  #Saves the new workbook for each Facility (or at least thats what I'm 
  #trying to do)       
  XLConnect::saveWorkbook(wb, name=paste("mywb",uniq[i],".xlsx",sep=""))
}
```

Comment: What error do you get? What is not working as youd like?

Comment: You are aware that `1+length(Transfers$Facility_ID)-1` is `length(Transfers$Facility_ID)` I suppose. In fact, `1+anything-1` equals `anything`.

Comment: Please describe your problem. You have two contradicting sentences: *I'm able to get the code inside the loop to run no problem...I just can't seem to see what I'm doing wrong in the loop itself.*

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question, the following will do what you want.

First, create a dataset, since you have not posted one in an easy to copy&paste form.

```
set.seed(12345)    # Make the results reproducible
Facility_ID <- rep(sprintf("%s%04d", c("P", "P", "W"), c(123, 345, 678)), each = 3)
Col1 <- sample(c("metal", "concrete", "mixed", "c and d", "municipal"), 9, TRUE)
Col2 <- sample(10, 9, TRUE)
Col3 <- sample(c("yes", "no"), 9, TRUE)

Transfers_ALL <- data.frame(Facility_ID, Col1, Col2, Col3)
```

Now the code.

```
write_sp_ALL <- function(DF, df_name){
  m <- as.data.frame(matrix('', nrow = 60, ncol = 60), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  nr <- nrow(DF)
  # places values in specific cells in the new empty matrix. 
  m[seq_len(nr), 3] <- as.character(DF[["Facility_ID"]])
  m[seq_len(nr), 8] <- as.character(DF[["Col1"]])

  file_name <- paste0("mywb", df_name, ".xlsx")  
  XLConnect::writeWorksheetToFile(file_name, m, sheet = "Sheet1", 
                            startRow = 13, startCol = 1, 
                            header = FALSE)

}

sp_ALL <- split(Transfers_ALL, Transfers_ALL[[1]])
nms <- names(sp_ALL)
lapply(seq_along(sp_ALL), function(i) 
  write_sp_ALL(sp_ALL[[i]], nms[i]))
```